# Tensorflow only works under root after drivers update

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, nvidia

I had a working Tensorflow for Python installation on my Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS Xenial / nVidia GTX 1080 Ti machine. Then, the **nVidia drivers got updated** from 374 to 384.90 (`nvidia-smi` reports `NVIDIA-SMI 384.90`).

Since then, I've **only been able to run my programs under `root` or in CPU mode**. For instance, when run using a regular user account, the  [MNIST example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/mnist) kept failing with a `CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR` error:

```
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:371] could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:338] could not destroy cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
F tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc:672] Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms( conv_parameters.ShouldIncludeWinogradNonfusedAlgo<T>(), &algorithms)
```

I have **tried reinstalling the drivers/CUDA/cudnn** in various combination several times, following the [official installation guide for TF r1.3](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux) throughout the process.

Whatever solutions I found online (mostly suggesting this is an issue with memory, which for 10GB cards trying to run MNIST is unlikely) have been tried out but have not been helpful, e.g.:

- https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1064
- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6606
- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8879
- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9132

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

#### Details

The update, as detailed in the logs in `/var/log/apt/history.log`

```
Start-Date: 2017-10-25  06:54:42¬
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade¬
Install: nvidia-384-dev:amd64 (384.90-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, automatic), libcuda1-384:amd64 (384.90-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, automatic), nvidia-opencl-icd-384:amd64 (384.90-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, automatic), nvidia-384:amd64 (384.90-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, automatic)¬
Upgrade: libcurl3:amd64 (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.3, 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.4), libcuda1-375:amd64 (375.66-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 384.90-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libicu55:amd64 (55.1-7ubuntu0.2, 55.1-7ubuntu0.3), chromium-browser:amd64 (61.0.3163.100-0ubuntu0.16.04.1306, 62.0.3202.62-0ubuntu0.16.04.1308), chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra:amd64 (61.0.3163.100-0ubuntu0.16.04.1306, 62.0.3202.62-0ubuntu0.16.04.1308), nvidia-375-dev:amd64 (375.66-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 384.90-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.16.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.2), mysql-common:amd64 (5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libmysqlclient20:amd64 (5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libicu-dev:amd64 (55.1-7ubuntu0.2, 55.1-7ubuntu0.3), icu-devtools:amd64 (55.1-7ubuntu0.2, 55.1-7ubuntu0.3), chromium-browser-l10n:amd64 (61.0.3163.100-0ubuntu0.16.04.1306, 62.0.3202.62-0ubuntu0.16.04.1308), curl:amd64 (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.3, 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.4), libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (2.16.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.2), nvidia-opencl-icd-375:amd64 (375.66-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 384.90-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.3, 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.4), nvidia-375:amd64 (375.66-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 384.90-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2:amd64 (2.16.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.2)¬
End-Date: 2017-10-25  06:56:00
```

I would be able to run, again under a regular user, the simple validation program from the [Tensorflow installation docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#validate_your_installation)

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

but the [MNIST example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/mnist) kept failing:

```
(venv-test)$~/tensorflow-validate/models/official/mnist$ python mnist.py
INFO:tensorflow:Using default config.
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_tf_random_seed': 1, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_session_config': None, '_model_dir': '/tmp/mnist_model', '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_save_checkpoints_steps': None}
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
2017-10-31 18:39:05.951324: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-10-31 18:39:05.951342: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-10-31 18:39:05.951346: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-10-31 18:39:05.951348: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-10-31 18:39:05.951366: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-10-31 18:39:06.591310: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:893] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2017-10-31 18:39:06.591682: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:955] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.582
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 10.91GiB
Free memory: 10.75GiB
2017-10-31 18:39:06.591693: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:976] DMA: 0
2017-10-31 18:39:06.591696: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:986] 0:   Y
2017-10-31 18:39:06.591701: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
2017-10-31 18:39:07.977441: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:371] could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
2017-10-31 18:39:07.977466: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:338] could not destroy cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
2017-10-31 18:39:07.977472: F tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc:672] Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms( conv_parameters.ShouldIncludeWinogradNonfusedAlgo<T>(), &algorithms)
```

I attempted reinstalling as follows:

Install CUDA 8

```
$ sudo apt install cuda-8-0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
cuda-8-0 is already the newest version (8.0.61-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

and

```
$ echo $CUDA_HOME
/usr/local/cuda-8.0
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
```

`libcupti-dev` is installed

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcupti-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libcupti-dev is already the newest version (7.5.18-0ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Create a new environment using `virtualenv`

```
$ virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 ~/venv-test
Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/represent/venv-test/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /home/represent/venv-test/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
```

installed Tensorflow using `pip` in `virtualenv`

(venv-test) represent@gatekeeper:/data/installers$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
    ...
    Successfully installed bleach-1.5.0 html5lib-0.9999999 markdown-2.6.9    numpy-1.13.3 protobuf-3.4.0 setuptools-36.6.0 six-1.11.0 tensorflow-gpu-1.3.0 tensorflow-tensorboard-0.1.8 wheel-0.30.0

Installed cuDNN 6.0.12

```
$ sudo dpkg -i libcudnn6_6.0.21-1+cuda8.0_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package libcudnn6.
(Reading database ... 226608 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libcudnn6_6.0.21-1+cuda8.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcudnn6 (6.0.21-1+cuda8.0) ...
Setting up libcudnn6 (6.0.21-1+cuda8.0) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/nvidia-384/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/nvidia-384/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link
```

and the dev package

```
$ sudo dpkg -i libcudnn6-dev_6.0.21-1+cuda8.0_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package libcudnn6-dev.
(Reading database ... 226614 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libcudnn6-dev_6.0.21-1+cuda8.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcudnn6-dev (6.0.21-1+cuda8.0) ...
Setting up libcudnn6-dev (6.0.21-1+cuda8.0) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/cudnn_v6.h to provide /usr/include/cudnn.h (libcudnn) in auto mode
```

Validating the installation

```
(venv-test)$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Sep 14 2017, 22:51:06)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.VERSION
'1.3.0'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We worked on this together with Jan Benes and found that the solution was to add to add our non-root user to `nvidia-persistenced` group. For example by `sudo usermod -a -G nvidia-persistenced our-nonroot-user`.

The reason behind this is, that default installation of nvidia driver (`nvidia-384` in our case) on Ubuntu creates user and group named `nvidia-persistenced` and this user is then used to run [NVIDIA Persistence Daemon](http://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/driver-persistence/index.html#persistence-daemon). If our user non-root didn't have access to files and written by this daemon, the MNIST example failed. It didn't fail for root (as it has access to everything) and stopped failing after we added our non-root user to the `nvidia-persistenced` group.